# SSISDB and Environments

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am attempting to set up an SSIS Project Deployment Model with Environment specific variables. I am in part using this tutorial as a guideline, [SSIS Parameters and Environments](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HcPJCBS_KY&t=597s), as well as [Deploy Integration Services (SSIS) Projects and Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/deploy-integration-services-ssis-projects-and-packages?view=sql-server-ver15).

Do Environments not work like I would plausibly expect them to? I need different connection strings for different environments. So I created those project level parameters in the SSIS solution and set the connection managers to use these Expressions. I deployed the project to the database and created the Environments I wanted (Development, Production)

Now I would *expect* when I configure the SQL job and set the environment as I need to, the *correct* variables would be pulled for the connection strings I need. As you can see in the screen shot SSMS is complaining that the development parameters don't exist in the Production environment (duh!).

So I have to kind of wonder, have I gone down the wrong rabbit hole?

Production - Use these connection strings
Development - Use these other connection strings

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have only one set of parameters in the SSIS project.
So instead of two parameters `ODSDevelopment` and `ODSProduction` you will have one parameter `ODSConnectionString`.
Then in the environments you will set up `ODSConnectionString` to point to Production or Development, depending on the environment.
In other words, word 'Production' may be used only in the environment name, but never in the parameter name.

Comment: So the parameter values in the VS Solution are just default values and will be overwritten, if you will, with the values I define in the SSISDB/Environments (Production, Development), do I have that right?

Comment: Yes. Also, if you set them as 'required', package will not start if you don't overwrite them, so you will not run package with default values by mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I guess what is still throwing me off is, in the job step, when I flip the environment, I'm expecting the parameter values to change. Isn't that what I should expect? I'm not seeing it do that.

Comment: On this view you can see environment variable name, not the value. You should define the same variable names in all environments. So in this view you will not see the values,

Comment: Well, try as I may, I cannot seem to flip the environment in the *job* and use the appropriate values from the environment parameters. It may just be late in the day and I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Update: Actually, I think I stumbled onto the solution. Fairly confident. Thanks!